# Why did Cox dislike Pfarrer since the beginning?

Tags: character, burn-after-reading

In *Burn After Reading*, as soon as the audience is introduced to Pfarrer, Cox starts having an uncomfortable back-and-forth with him, to the extent that it becomes obvious he dislikes Pfarrer. Later, it is revealed that Pfarrer is having an affair with Katie.

However, by the end of the movie, as Cox inquires Ted whether he's his wife's lover, it becomes clear he suspects an affair, but doesn't know who is involved.

**Why did Osbourne Cox dislike Harry Pfarrer**, then? Is it a play on the stereotypes portrayed in the movie?